# Create a Stack Overflow-like form

Tags: javascript, forms, input

I'm trying to create a form which prints the input directly beneath it, just like here on Stack Overflow when you write a question. However, since I'm new to Javascript and such, I don't know how to search for the correct function (I don't know the correct name for this technique).

Just a push in the right direction will already be a big help! Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Javascript will do it very simply if it is just plain text, however, the form on here parses the text and uses MarkDown to output it with the correct formatting.

Comment: maybe you can search for JS markdown editors but I think S.O. has his self-made editor

Comment: Well, it doesn't have to be a markdown editor, it's just plain text and I thought SO was a good example, as everyone here has used it. If you could point me in the right direction @Mike, that would be perfect!

Comment: See my answer below. That should do the trick. It's nice and simple but if you need me to explain anything, just comment below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
        function myFunction()
        {
            var input = document.getElementById('fname')
            var div = document.getElementById('text');
            div.innerHTML = escape(input.value);
        }
        </script>
        <input type="text" id="fname" onkeyup="myFunction()">
        <div id="text"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It makes perfect sense. I can read Javascript, just don't know it well enough to write it yet. The question you linked to in the comments before was bugged, as it would my name like RRoRobRobbRobbeRobberRobbert even though the input field was Robbert. But this works! Thanks again!

Comment: Have you every tried http://codecademy.com ? If not, you should, it's great and hopefully will help you a lot.

Comment: Do note the obvious HTML injection vulnerability in this sample though :)

Comment: It's going to be offline, just a tool for a colleague to create an HTML-table without her needing to learn how to make one by hand. But thanks for the heads up @AKX!

Comment: @Mike I finished Codecademy's Javascript course, but don't remember I got something like this as an assignment.

Comment: You may not have done, but codecademy certainly helps, also http://www.w3schools.com is a good reference site.

Comment: @AKX I have added the escape method, however, the OP may want to allow certain HTML tags. But this is just a crude example.